# Setting a variable in R to automate a script

Tags: r

I'm looking to set a variable in R that may change based on my needs.

For example I would like to assign `region <- "Zmutt"` and use `region` throughout my script where `metadata <- metadata[metadata$gl_name == 'region' & metadata$substrate == 'sed',]` and the variable `region` will be interpreted as `"Zmutt"`.

TIA
Edit: removed second question for clarity.

Comment: Remove the single quotes. `metadata <- metadata[metadata$gl_name == region & metadata$substrate == 'sed',]`

Answer (score 0):

Ah. It's much simpler than I thought. Here is my solution:

```
region = "Zmutt"
metadata <- metadata[metadata$gl_name == region & metadata$substrate == 'sed',]
```